# ng not recognized and npm run can't find package.json

Tags: node.js, angular, package.json

Whenever I try to create a new project with angular I receive the below error:

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smaS5.png)

however I added the path of angular to the environment and set each and every solution on websites.

and if this is a node.js version issue related how can I update it.

Comment: Please: Always copy-paste error messages or code, never printscreen. Give more informations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng` is the keyword for using angular cli so the correct way to create a new project is to run `ng new projectName`

Meanwhile a command such as `npm run start` executes a script in package.json (in this case `ng serve`). If you run `npm run ng new projectName` then npm will look for a script called `ng` + some other parameters called `new` and `projectName`

Answer (score 0):

To use the angular CLI command to create a new project or component, you need to use the angular CLI that starts with `ng`. For more help, just type `ng help` to see the available commands.

`npm run ...` is used to run the scripts available in your package.json such as `npm run start`, `npm run test` and more.

So to create a new project, the correct command is `ng new auto-project` or with npx `npx ng new auto-project`.